# Does Three20 offer simplified installations that replace CoreData framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, three20

I'm new to iOS development but experienced in MVC patterns. I need to know if there's some way to avoid dealing with CoreData framework using merely three20 API.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do with Core Data?

Answer (score 2):

Three20 and Core Data are for the most part orthogonal. The one certainly doesn't preclude or replace the other. They can be used together, and perfectly functional iOS apps can be built without either.

In particular, Core Data is all about managing and persistently storing an object graph.

Three20 is about implementing the core of the Facebook app, including lots of UI widgets, and infrastructure for fetching and displaying data that originates on the network.

In many cases, you won't see both together, because the apps that want to load everything from the network often don't want to store that data on the device. But, on the other hand, I've seen people talk about implementing Three20 models backed by Core Data storage.

Perhaps you can elaborate on what it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm building an app in which i would like to navigate through it without internet connection. To what extend Three20 cache could be use as a replacement to CoreData to simulate offline navigation?

Comment: It's certainly possible to leverage Three20's caching functionality to store the results of network operations for offline use. You may have some work to do to get your cache policies set properly, and build your models to fall back gracefully to the cached data. But I'm sure that it's possible. If your data isn't coming from the network in the first place, however, then you're going to be fighting the framework, because that's a strong assumption in the Three20 code.